# Drag and drop not working in grid container in Godot 3

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm working on the UI for a tower defense game for my university's video game development club using Godot. I have code to drag towers from the menu onto the board, but it's not working properly. I've tested it in a separate file and it works fine, but as soon as I run it in the actual program, which has the turrets in a GridContainer, it stops working. Each turret is a TextureRect currently, all of which are children of a GridContainer, which itself is a child of another TextureRect which is the background. Finally, the root of the scene is a MarginContainer.

Here's the code. It's basically just the official drag and drop demo but modified for TextureRects.

```
extends TextureRect

func get_drag_data(pos):
    var prev = TextureRect.new()
    prev.texture = texture
    prev.rect_size = Vector2(50,50)
    set_drag_preview(prev)
    return texture

func can_drop_data(pos, data):
    return true

func drop_data(pos, data):
    texture = data
```

So my question is, how can I make drag and drop work when the things that get dragged are in a container? I could do this without containers, but that sounds like it would lead to some bad UI design so I'd really rather not.

Comment: Hi Brian, could you give some more information about your project structure? What do you drag? The container or the the content of the container? Do you get any error message? Do you see the right texture as drag preview?

Comment: Thanks for the response! Currently, for testing, you're just dragging the container's children onto each other, and the texture of the TextureRect you drag onto will become that of the one you were dragging. The preview is correct, and there are no error messages given.

Comment: Can you add a `print(self)` in the `get_drag_data` and `drop_data` functions to see you are dropping the texture in the right object. It is rather obvious but just to make sure, you have the script connected to all your TextureRect objects?